# FlyingSaucer with openpdf doesn't render flex box correctly

Tags: java, flexbox, pdf-generation, flying-saucer, openpdf

I want to render a PDF document using [latest](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.xhtmlrenderer/flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf) FLyingSaucer

```
build.gradle:

implementation 'org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf:9.1.22'
```

Input HTML document (almost a [copy from W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_flexbox)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: DodgerBlue;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Create a Flex Container</h1>

<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

A sample code (as  JUnit test):

```
class FlexTest {

  @Test
  void flexTest() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    final String htmlContent =
        IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream("input.html"), Charset.defaultCharset());

    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(htmlContent);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(new FileOutputStream("output.pdf"));
  }
}
```

It works fine except the `display: flex` is not rendered correctly. It looks like it's rendered as a regular `<div>`:

[image]

Is the flex box supported by FlyingSaucer/openpdf? I didn't find any note that it isn't.

Comment: just because you mention openpdf, pdfhtml/itext have [flex support](https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/flexbox-suport-in-pdfhtml)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flying-saucer doesn't support Flex, and will likely never support it.

The CSS supported by flying-saucer is limited to [CSS 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/) and most of [CSS paged media](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-page-3/).